# Context-free grammar from language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm trying to come up with a context-free grammar for the following language:

L = {a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>m+n</sup> | 0 <= n <= m}

My thinking is that i can rewrite this to

L = {a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>n</sup>c<sup>n</sup>c<sup>m</sup> | 0 <= n <= m}

and then create the grammar

S -> aSc | B

B -> bBc | ^

The problem is that this grammar doesnt capture 0 <= n <= m and I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This problem isn't really a programming problem per se. I'd suggest cs.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: I don't think that language is context-free, and you should be able to prove that it isn't with the pumping lemma.

Comment: n<=m is not context free